# How to optimize this linq query? (with OrderBy and ThenBy)

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

I have currently in a table about 90k rows. And it's will grow up about 1kk ~ 5kk before i execute a clean up and put all rows in a "historical table". So, when i run this following query (MyEntities is a ObjectSet):

```
MyEntities.Skip(amount * page).Take(amount).ToList();
```

This query takes about 1.2s... but when i run this following query with OrderBy and ThenBy:

```
MyEntities.OrderBy(b => b.Day).ThenBy(b => b.InitialHour).Skip(amount * page).Take(amount).ToList();
```

This query takes about 5.7s. There is a way to optimize the second query?

Comment: Haev you got suitable indexes on the tables in the database?

Comment: What is your backing store for the table?  If SQL, then you might just need some indexes

Comment: Why are you forcing Linq to do the work a database query should be doing? SQL queries/procedures are far more efficient at handling such a large number of records.

Comment: @SpikeX: What makes you think the database isn't doing this? One of the benefits of LINQ is *specifying* the query in C#, but it *executing* as SQL.

Comment: @SpikeX presumably this is a Linq to entities query, not a linq to object query.

Comment: If this was using linq to objects it wouldn't even be 5.7s fast, it would be much slower, so I doubt the sort is client side.

Comment: @Servy: Actually I suspect LINQ to Objects is *quite* capable of handling 90K records in 5 seconds. That's a *lot* of time for a modern machine, and 90K records really isn't that many.

Comment: @JonSkeet as long as the objects are already in memory. (5 seconds after ToList())

Comment: @AdrianIftode: Sure. I think it's reasonable to talk about cases where *either* things are in memory already *or* the query is being executed in the database...

Comment: @Chris i put now a index with `Day` and `Hour` and the query takes 5.5s.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was thinking it would take longer than 5s just to pull the data from the DB to memory, not the sort.

Comment: @Servy: It turns out that's exactly what it *was* doing :) (90K rows really isn't *that* much data though... I'm not surprised it can be fetched in 5s, if the row size is reasonable small.)

Comment: Huh.  Well, I'll be damned.  I've been working in the SharePoint world for too long (It's much, much slower).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Check that it really *is* happening in the database (instead of fetching all entities, then sorting)
- Make sure that both `Day` and `InitialHour` are indexed.
- Check the generated SQL isn't doing anything crazy (check the query plan)

EDIT: Okay, so it looks like `MyEntities` is actually declared as `IEnumerable<MyEntity>`, which means *everything* will be done in-process... all your LINQ calls will be via `Enumerable.Select` etc, rather than `Queryable.Select` etc. Just change the *declared* type of `MyEntities` to `IQueryable<MyEntity>` and watch it fly...

Comment: I create a index with Day and InitialHour, and the query takes 5.5s... i'll look for what sql was generated.

Comment: After i run the second query i call `MyEntities.ToTraceString()` and the query is `SELECT [All table columns] FROM Tickets`. Why there isn't ORDER BY, TOP...?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: Well, what's the *declared* type of `MyEntities`? Is it `IEnumerable<MyEntity>` by any chance?

Comment: It is a cast to `IEnumerable<MyEntity>` of a `ObjectSet<MyEntity>`.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: Right, then that's the problem. You want `IQueryable<MyEntity>`. I suspect you'll find that's much faster :)

Comment: It is flying 0.7s ~ 1.2s /o/ - Thanks Jon.. again! =)

Answer (score 1):

For reading data from your DB, it's usually a good idea to create custom SQL Views, say one View per grid and one View per Form that you want to populate.

In this example, you would create a view that does the sorting for you, then map that View to an Entity in Entity Framework, then query that Entity using LINQ.

This is nice, clean, readable, maintainable and as optimal as you can make it.

Good luck!